# What is the proper Islamic way to conduct the function of marriage (e.g. Nikkah, and Walima)?

Tags: nikah, wedding

I lived in Pakistan, there the people do different functions for the celebrations of marriage (e.g. Hina Rasam, Barat, and Walima). In my knowledge, only Walima is acceptable in Islam (I've read some hadiths). So, my question is

Is it right to exhibit the bride and groom in the event of Walima, where people taking pictures and giving them greetings?

Or isn't it enough that we should only give them food (food of Walima) and meet with them (celebrate) and say goodbye to the guests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culture you people follow I believe, is wholly influenced by Hindu traditions. In Islam, the simpler the marriage the better. Even the very Walima is NOT obligatory. It's just a way to show happiness that the couple is married. Other than that, a simple Nikah contract and you can live together. I do not need to provide "evidence" as you could easily Google it out or ask a Mufti.

About the "taking pictures", sit and think. WHY are you taking pictures? Islam does not permit taking photos of women as they must be hidden, and of course, if taking photos means that men and women must mix, then strictly no.

As for greetings, it's ok for the men greet the groom and the women to greet the bride, NOT with opposite sexes. And of course the Mahrams such as father-in-law, mother-in-law can do so, but probably afterwards as the wedding party will have segregation.

Fear Allah and do it Islam's way. Relatives and friends WILL push you to do it in a Haraam way. If you listen to them, then don't be sad if the marriage breaks apart or one of the couple starts hating the other.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @ElFlea. Further, I strongly agree with the 2nd and 4th part of your answer, may Allah show us the right path.